# Laravel API Resources | Multiple APIs

Tags: php, laravel, rest, laravel-5

I am consuming multiple "Restaurant Reviews" REST APIs which return different structures. I need to define a uniform structure for these reviews so I can group them together and deal with them as a collection.

It seems that using [Eloquent Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources) is on par with what I need.

Looking at the implementation here on this [Medium Blog](https://medium.com/@jeffochoa/consuming-third-pary-apis-with-laravel-resources-c13a0c7dc945), the method `toArray` is used by default when calling `return MyResource::make($data)->resolve();`. I do not want to defy the convention of Laravel, since that is why I am using the framework. However, I need all three different structures to have the same uniform ending structures which would lead to lots of `if` / `else` and `yelpToArray(), foursquareToArray(), etc ...` in the `toArray` method.

What is the most "Laravel" way to accomplish this?

Comment: what about way of passing your data structure type as parameter to resource file then show fields refer parameter value?

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are attempting to accomplish here is consume resources from various apis, and drop your api in between these so that you can create agnostic resources to consume?

Comment: @adam Yes, I want to fetch resources from several APIs and turn the various results into a collection of uniform structured data.  Example: one response may have 'website_url' as a property and another may have 'web_url'.

Comment: @TT4M.C One way to accomplish this might be to create a mapper for each vendor and map the respective properties into a common object for reuse in your own API.